# Is there any way to enable caching in spring for only one method?

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I have a spring project in which I have implemented the caching on the method level. Now I have a requirement to stop the caching for the whole project. I stopped it by flag to set false.

Now I wanted to enable the caching only for one method. Is there any way to enable caching just for one method?

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheHelper.APPLICATION_CACHE_NAME, key = "T(ca.sunlife.grs.core.cache.CacheHelper).generateApplicationCacheKey(T(ca.sunlife.grs.core.cache.CacheKey).CACHE_GET_MEMBER,#request.getClientId() + #request.getPlanId() + #request.getMemberNumber() +#request.getMemberIndicator())", unless = "#result== null")
public GetMemberMqResponse getMemberWithCache(GetMemberRequest request) throws Exception {
    GetMemberMqRequest mqRequest = getMemberDomainToMqMapper.toMqRequest(request);
    GrsLogger.info(this, "MQRequest is:" + mqRequest.getRequestString());
    return getMemberMqResponseParser.parseMqResponse(grsMqTransactionOrMockRunner.run(mqRequest));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [NoOpCacheManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/support/NoOpCacheManager.html) and drive which CacheManager is enabled using Spring [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-java).

> public class NoOpCacheManager extends Object implements CacheManager
>
> A basic, no operation CacheManager implementation suitable for disabling caching, typically used for backing cache declarations without an actual backing store.
>   Will simply accept any items into the cache not actually storing them.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new CaffeineCacheManager(); //Example implementation
}

@Bean
@Profile("noCaching")
@Primary
public CacheManager noOpCacheManager() {
    return new NoOpCacheManager();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `@Cacheable` only on the method which you want to be cached and remove it from the methods which you do not want to be cached.

Comment: Is there any other way to stop it, like by using any annotation we can stop it .

Comment: I am not sure but I think there no other way, If you enable the caching at project or class level you will have to disable it at the method level.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question of how to disable caching for the whole project.

Comment: I am sorry @LucasP but the question is how to enable caching only for one method as you can read `Now I have a requirement to enable the caching only for one method. Is there any way to enable caching for only one method`